# Not able to connect to kafka brokers

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I've deployed https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/tree/master/charts/cp-kafka on my on prem k8s cluster. 
I'm trying to expose it my using a TCP controller with nginx.

My TCP nginx configmap looks like

```
data:
  "<zookeper-tcp-port>": <namespace>/cp-zookeeper:2181
  "<kafka-tcp-port>": <namespace>/cp-kafka:9092
```

And i've made the corresponding entry in my nginx ingress controller

```
  - name: <zookeper-tcp-port>-tcp
    port: <zookeper-tcp-port>
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: <zookeper-tcp-port>-tcp
  - name: <kafka-tcp-port>-tcp
    port: <kafka-tcp-port>
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: <kafka-tcp-port>-tcp
```

Now I'm trying to connect to my kafka instance. 
When i just try to connect to the IP and port using kafka tools, I get the error message

```
Unable to determine broker endpoints from Zookeeper.
One or more brokers have multiple endpoints for protocol PLAIN...
Please proved bootstrap.servers value in advanced settings
[<cp-broker-address-0>.cp-kafka-headless.<namespace>:<port>][<ip>]
```

When I enter, what I assume are the correct broker addresses (I've tried them all...) I get a time out. There are no logs coming from the nginx controler excep

```
[08/Apr/2020:15:51:12 +0000]TCP200000.000
[08/Apr/2020:15:51:12 +0000]TCP200000.000
[08/Apr/2020:15:51:14 +0000]TCP200000.001
```

From the pod `kafka-zookeeper-0` I'm gettting loads of

```
[2020-04-08 15:52:02,415] INFO Accepted socket connection from /<ip:port> (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2020-04-08 15:52:02,415] WARN Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x0, likely client has closed socket (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
[2020-04-08 15:52:02,415] INFO Closed socket connection for client /<ip:port>  (no session established for client) (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

Though I'm not sure these have anything to do with it?

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to connect from cluster LAN or it is being exposed to the web? if yes, care to detail?

Comment: Within the cluster it's not a problem. There I can connect straight to each broker. But for traffic comming externally I want the `cp-kafka` service to connect me to the brokers via the `cp-kafka-headless` service. Or am I wrong in thinking this way?

Comment: since it's a [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services), it works more as a DNS discovery service for the stateful pods, it has no IP address. A solution would be to create a external service directly to the cp-kafka-0. I'll write an example and expand this explanation in an answer I'm preparing for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- Change the value `nodeport.enabled` to `true` inside `cp-kafka/values.yaml` before deploying.
- Change the service name and ports in you TCP NGINX Configmap and Ingress object.
- Set `bootstrap-server` on your kafka tools to `<Cluster_External_IP>:31090`

---

**Explanation:**

> The [Headless Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) was created alongside the StatefulSet. The created service will **not** be given a `clusterIP`, but will instead simply include a list of `Endpoints`.
>    These `Endpoints` are then used to generate instance-specific DNS records in the form of:
>     `<StatefulSet>-<Ordinal>.<Service>.<Namespace>.svc.cluster.local`

It creates a DNS name for each pod, e.g:

```
[ root@curl:/ ]$ nslookup my-confluent-cp-kafka-headless
Server:    10.0.0.10
Address 1: 10.0.0.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local

Name:      my-confluent-cp-kafka-headless
Address 1: 10.8.0.23 my-confluent-cp-kafka-1.my-confluent-cp-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 2: 10.8.1.21 my-confluent-cp-kafka-0.my-confluent-cp-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
Address 3: 10.8.3.7 my-confluent-cp-kafka-2.my-confluent-cp-kafka-headless.default.svc.cluster.local
```

- This is what makes this services connect to each other inside the cluster.

---

I've gone through a lot of trial and error, until I realized how it was supposed to be working. Based your TCP Nginx Configmap I believe you faced the same issue.

- The [Nginx ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/) asks for: `<PortToExpose>: "<Namespace>/<Service>:<InternallyExposedPort>"`.
- I realized that you don't need to expose the Zookeeper, since it's a internal service and handled by kafka brokers.
- I also realized that you are trying to expose `cp-kafka:9092` which is the headless service, also only used internally, as I explained above.
- In order to get outside access **you have to set the parameters `nodeport.enabled` to `true`** as stated here: [External Access Parameters](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts/blob/master/charts/cp-kafka/README.md#external-access).
- It adds one service to each kafka-N pod during chart deployment.
- Then you change your configmap to map to one of them:

```
data:
"31090": default/demo-cp-kafka-0-nodeport:31090
```

Note that the service created has the selector `statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: demo-cp-kafka-0` this is how the service identifies the pod it is intended to connect to.

- Edit the nginx-ingress-controller:

```
- containerPort: 31090
  hostPort: 31090
  protocol: TCP
```

- Set your kafka tools to `<Cluster_External_IP>:31090`

---

**Reproduction:**
- Snippet edited in `cp-kafka/values.yaml`:

```
nodeport:
  enabled: true
  servicePort: 19092
  firstListenerPort: 31090
```

- Deploy the chart:

```
$ helm install demo cp-helm-charts
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
demo-cp-control-center-6d79ddd776-ktggw    1/1     Running   3          113s
demo-cp-kafka-0                            2/2     Running   1          113s
demo-cp-kafka-1                            2/2     Running   0          94s
demo-cp-kafka-2                            2/2     Running   0          84s
demo-cp-kafka-connect-79689c5c6c-947c4     2/2     Running   2          113s
demo-cp-kafka-rest-56dfdd8d94-79kpx        2/2     Running   1          113s
demo-cp-ksql-server-c498c9755-jc6bt        2/2     Running   2          113s
demo-cp-schema-registry-5f45c498c4-dh965   2/2     Running   3          113s
demo-cp-zookeeper-0                        2/2     Running   0          112s
demo-cp-zookeeper-1                        2/2     Running   0          93s
demo-cp-zookeeper-2                        2/2     Running   0          74s

$ kubectl get svc
NAME                         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
demo-cp-control-center       ClusterIP   10.0.13.134   <none>        9021/TCP            50m
demo-cp-kafka                ClusterIP   10.0.15.71    <none>        9092/TCP            50m
demo-cp-kafka-0-nodeport     NodePort    10.0.7.101    <none>        19092:31090/TCP     50m
demo-cp-kafka-1-nodeport     NodePort    10.0.4.234    <none>        19092:31091/TCP     50m
demo-cp-kafka-2-nodeport     NodePort    10.0.3.194    <none>        19092:31092/TCP     50m
demo-cp-kafka-connect        ClusterIP   10.0.3.217    <none>        8083/TCP            50m
demo-cp-kafka-headless       ClusterIP   None          <none>        9092/TCP            50m
demo-cp-kafka-rest           ClusterIP   10.0.14.27    <none>        8082/TCP            50m
demo-cp-ksql-server          ClusterIP   10.0.7.150    <none>        8088/TCP            50m
demo-cp-schema-registry      ClusterIP   10.0.7.84     <none>        8081/TCP            50m
demo-cp-zookeeper            ClusterIP   10.0.9.119    <none>        2181/TCP            50m
demo-cp-zookeeper-headless   ClusterIP   None          <none>        2888/TCP,3888/TCP   50m
```

- Create the TCP configmap:

```
$ cat nginx-tcp-configmap.yaml 
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  31090: "default/demo-cp-kafka-0-nodeport:31090"

$ kubectl apply -f nginx-tcp.configmap.yaml
configmap/tcp-services created
```

- Edit the Nginx Ingress Controller:

```
$ kubectl edit deploy nginx-ingress-controller -n kube-system

$kubectl get deploy nginx-ingress-controller -n kube-system -o yaml
{{{suppressed output}}}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31090
          hostPort: 31090
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
```

- My ingress is on IP `35.226.189.123`, now let's try to connect from outside the cluster. For that I'll connect to another VM where I have a minikube, so I can use `kafka-client` pod to test:

```
user@minikube:~$ kubectl get pods
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kafka-client   1/1     Running   0          17h

user@minikube:~$ kubectl exec kafka-client -it -- bin/bash

root@kafka-client:/# kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server 35.226.189.123:31090 --topic demo-topic --from-beginning --timeout-ms 8000 --max-messages 1
Wed Apr 15 18:19:48 UTC 2020
Processed a total of 1 messages
root@kafka-client:/#
```

As you can see, I was able to access the kafka from outside.

- If you need external access to Zookeeper as well I'll leave a service model for you:

`zookeeper-external-0.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: cp-zookeeper
    pod: demo-cp-zookeeper-0
  name: demo-cp-zookeeper-0-nodeport
  namespace: default
spec:
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - name: external-broker
    nodePort: 31181
    port: 12181
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 31181
  selector:
    app: cp-zookeeper
    statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name: demo-cp-zookeeper-0
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
```

- It will create a service for it:

```
NAME                           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
demo-cp-zookeeper-0-nodeport   NodePort    10.0.5.67     <none>        12181:31181/TCP     2s
```

- Patch your configmap:

```
data:
  "31090": default/demo-cp-kafka-0-nodeport:31090
  "31181": default/demo-cp-zookeeper-0-nodeport:31181
```

- Add the Ingress rule:

```
        ports:
        - containerPort: 31181
          hostPort: 31181
          protocol: TCP
```

- Test it with your external IP:

```
pod/zookeeper-client created
user@minikube:~$ kubectl exec -it zookeeper-client -- /bin/bash
root@zookeeper-client:/# zookeeper-shell 35.226.189.123:31181
Connecting to 35.226.189.123:31181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled
```

If you have any doubts, let me know in the comments!

Comment: Wow, thanks! Great answer, much appreciated. Just one thing, why would you set the nginx ingress controller port to the `demo-cp-zookeeper-0-nodeport` actual nodeport? i.e `31090` and not `19092`? I did the other way and set the nginx controller to map to `19092` and it works.. Though when that worked I tried remaking the nodeport service to a cluter IP, but that didn't work as expected... Anyway, huge thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Actually I copied from the service generated by the helm chart, it does not make much sense for me either but it worked so I let it as it were, but you are technically correct in using the Port specially if using it as `ClusterIP`. The range of ports between 30000 - 32767 is reserved for `NodePorts` and it would not work on a `ClusterIP` type.

Comment: So, by re-defining the service as ```
    port: 19092
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 19092```
I'd be able to defined it as ClusterIP and use that instead of the nodeport?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, and remove the line `nodeporte: 31090`. Did you tried it?

Comment: Not working... Seeing `2020/04/17 16:32:23 [error] 352#352: *710385 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <ip>, server: 0.0.0.0:39092, upstream: "<ip>:19092", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0` in my nginx-ingress-controller pod... 
My nginx configmap is defined as `"39092": <namespace>/cp-kafka-0-nodeport:19092.. Can't really get it to work without the `nodeport` definition...

Comment: `- containerPort: 31092
          name: nodeport-0
          protocol: TCP` is defined in in `ports:` in the statefulset, that's probably why. I need to redefine those and and add the new ports in `EXTERNAL://${HOST_IP}:$((31092 + ${KAFKA_BROKER_ID}))` defined as `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`. That should resolve it, i think? I'll give that a try tomorrow..

Comment: It's a chain of events: 1) you set the port for the service (i.e: 19092), 2) you patch the nginx configmap to "19092": <namespace>/cp-kafka-0-nodeport:19092, 3) change the nginx ingress controller to the same port 19092. Now the connection from outside is handled by nginx IP on the port 19092, and forwarded to the service listening on port 19092 internally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211886/discussion-between-willrof-and-t3ng1l).