# Exposing Multiple Confluent Kafka Brokers Publicly using ingress-nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-ingress, confluent-platform

I am trying to expose cp-kafka brokers publicly using the ingress-nginx and I happen to see [this Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105315/not-able-to-connect-to-kafka-brokers) The answers only shows one broker is exposed outside the cluster. Say, If I have 3 brokers running, how can I expose all 3 Kafka brokers using the nginx ingress controller?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka is using binary protocol so you cannot use http routing.

You would need to expose brokers on a separate ports. Read this page in ingress-nginx docs: [Exposing TCP and UDP services](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/). The answer you linked already explains how to do this for one port/service. Now all you have to do is expose two more ports. Since you cannot open a port number more than once, you need to expose every broker on a separate port.

Comment: Thanks @matt. I understand that we need to expose the container ports but shouldn't we also expose the same ports from the ingress nginx kubernetes service?

Comment: You cannot expose the same ports since you cant open the same port twice or more. Does this answer your question or did I misunderstand sth?

Comment: I got your point. I am now trying to expose one Kafka broker and getting this error in the ingress controller log:
`Service "default/confluent-cp-kafka-0-nodeport" does not have any active Endpoint for TCP port 31090`
And when I try to connect to Kafka publicly, I get the connection refused error.
Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you read the comments section? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211886/discussion-between-willrof-and-t3ng1l It looks like they have discussed this there.

Comment: I have fixed the above error `Service "default/confluent-cp-kafka-0-nodeport" does not have any active Endpoint for TCP port 31090` but I am still getting the connection refused error when I try to connect to Kafka. Is there any other document I can follow to expose Kafka using ingress-nginx?

Comment: Most probably you misconfigured service selector. It should match the lables on pod you want to forward to

Comment: I cross verified it, and it's all looking good. The only thing I had changed was the node port mentioned in the TCP ConfigMap, i.e, 31090 to 19092. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing the tcp-services configMap data to the one below.

`31090: "default/demo-cp-kafka-0-nodeport:19092"`